# PostBack troubles with event handler for a ListBox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have 2 listbox and 3 buttons. 1 listbox is populated via Page Load from a database, the second one is empty. Both listbox has the event SelectedIndexChanged; when I select an item and press the button (either >> or <<) which handle click event, postback happens and the item is passed to the other listbox. The problem occurs with the third button which is "Save", so, if for some reason I have an item selected and press "Save", it first calls the event SelectedIndexChanged and then the event that handle "Save" button. Another thing is that the application use a lot of PostBack, basically any event that happens will PostBack.

[Image from the problem itself.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdStu.png)

As you can see, an item is selected but if I press the Save button, then PostBack happens and the first thing that happens is the event SelectedIndexChanged (which moves the item to the other listbox) and then the Save button event. Is there any way to solve this? I have read solutions using Javascript + Ajax but it would take me a lot of time since I have no idea about them.

Comment: I think, the lost of the focus means, that the SelectedIndex has changed.

Comment: Mmm..Sorry for my bad english but I don't understand what you wanted to say with "the lost of the focus"?

Comment: In the moment you click your button, every other control loses it's focus. I am not sure, but maybe this will raise the SelectedIndexChange-event of your ListBoxes.

Comment: I mean, whenever a PostBack happens, since an element is selected, the event SeletectedIndexChanged does also happen even if I called another event like Click from Save button. Thats why I am having trouble with the postback and that event.

Comment: I was wondering if using asp.net UpdatePanel with trigger would work?